# node.js routing- what is actually going on here

Tags: node.js, url-routing

This is a simple node app with routing. Code follows :

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

var route = {
    routes:{},
    for:function(path, handler){

        console.log("route path = "+path);
        this.routes[path]= handler; 
    }

};

route.for("/start", function(request, response){

    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});

    response.write("Hello");
    response.end();
});

route.for("/finish", function(request, response){

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Goodbye");
    response.end();
});

function onRequest(request, response) {

    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
    if(typeof route.routes[pathname] ==='function'){

       console.log(" main pathname = "+pathname);
       route.routes[pathname](request, response);
   }else{
       response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
       response.end("404 Not Found");
     }

}// END OF ONrEQUEST

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(9999);
console.log("Server has started at 9999.");
```

When I run the app I see in console:

*route path = /start*

*route path = /finish*

*Server has started at 9999.*

When I hit at http://localhost:9999/finish, I find in console :

*Request for /finish received.*

*main pathname = /finish*

I am trying to understand the code- at first  the `route` object variable is constructed.

**Q1)** How does the `for` property work there ?

Let us look at the following line :

```
route.for("/start", function(request, response){
```

It seems to be related with the `for` property in whatever ways.

**Q2)** How is it related with the `for` property ?

Comment: Because it is defined in the `route` variable and now you're calling it. Simple

Comment: hmm, really ... in the answer form instead of a comment ?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is defined in the route variable and now you're calling it.

It is defined in the `route` variable as a property, and you're calling this property *(basically the function)* and storing the routes in it.

The second part is `onRequest` method, where you check whether the requested URL exists in your app or not. And call the respective method based on the URL requested other wise respond with `404`.

PS: The logic is fine, but it doesn't handle the type of request `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` etc..

Comment: So what is the rule to set a value for an object  property ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Pass another argument to your `for` function and store it too like `GET` `POST` and check on request that which one was called.

Comment: probably that is not what I asked in comment.

Comment: I don't get it, would you like to elaborate? Setting an object property is just `obj.propertyName = 'value'` if you asked this..

Comment: isn't `for` a property of `route` ? `obj.propertyName = 'value'` is not applied here.

Comment: Yes it is, and its type is `function` so it can be `invoked` actually. If you want to override the property, you just assign something new to it *(as I did in above comment)*.